# SQL Datatable error "Value cannot be null."

Tags: asp.net, sql, datatable

I am executing a sql query, and I am getting an error **Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataTable**

**Code:**

```
                strSQLHost = "select HostBase.AppName from HostBase where HostBase.appid=0" 
                Dim dtHost As DataTable
                Dim daHost As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQLHost, conn)
                daHost.Fill(dtHost)
```

The error occurs at the `daHost.Fill(dtHost)`
When I run this query in SQL Enterprise manager, I get a value of 'None'. It's a valid value, not a null value.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the last `'` on your statement

I think it should read like this:

```
strSQLHost = "select Host.AppName from HostBase where HostBase.appid=0"
```

And instantiate your DataTable before passing it in:

```
Dim dtHost As DataTable = new DataTable()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just turn the rest of the line into a comment?

Comment: lcarus, that is a comment line. I did remove it, but no luck

Comment: @JeffO OP updated his question. He had a `'` right after appid=0  and I thought he meant to concatenate the output of dmRow("appid") or something like that he had written initially

Comment: Dim dtHost As DataTable = new DataTable() was the answer. Thanks very much lcarus !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select Host.AppName from HostBase where HostBase.appid=0
```

Seems like you're mixing table names when you only refer to one table:  HostBase.  You can't use table: Host in this query without including it in some sort of join (Even if it turned into a Cartesian Product) This is the change.

```
select HostBase.AppName from HostBase where HostBase.appid=0
```

Put a break and see the exact value of the string variable: strSQLHost

Comment: sorry... that was a typo on my part in the original posting